# Microsoft Excel Using Match result

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-match

I have a drop down that I call match on. Can I directly incorporate matches result into a formula.

For example I am trying to say

```
=C(MATCH(J15,A1:A52,0))
```

I am using match to find the second component of the cells location. I am using Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(I23,'State Sales Tax'!A2:A52,0)+1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(J15,A1:A52,0))
```